# vim special mark behavior?

Tags: vim, centos7

I was just started to looked at vim plugin and trying to write one for myself. I want to use marking features of Vim. I found the following snipped in a book as:

```
nnoremap <leader>g :set operatorfunc=GrepOperator<cr>g@
vnoremap <leader>g :<c-u>call GrepOperator(visualmode())<cr>

function! GrepOperator(type)
   if a:type ==# 'char'
        normal! `[v`]y
    else
        return
    endif

    echom shellescape(@@)
endfunction
```

The behavior of `[ and `] as mentioned in vim help and here in the function is not same. Vim help says as:

```
`[            To the first character of previously changed or yanked text.
`]            To the last character of the previously changed or yanked text.
```

when I type the following command in normal mode in vim:

```
normal! `[v`]y
```

with a file it yanked lines based on what I have done previously(how many lines above or below I have changed text or yanked).

But if I call the same command with above function bonded with motion-operator
the behavior is not the same as it echos a character under the current cursor.

> The motion i used is: `vi(<leader>g`

Why both the behavior is not as per vim help documentations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, Vim "overloads" the `'[` and `']` change marks to represent the moved-over text in an operator function. This avoided introducing another special mark. The general `:help '[` does not apply here.

Strictly speaking, operator functions are only for normal mode `{opfunc}{motion}`, but usually you also want them to work in visual mode, too (`{Visual}{opfunc}`). You've defined both `:nmap` and `:vmap`, too.

The `type` function argument is how the operator function is able to differentiate between the two modes. As you've used `vi(<leader>g`, this is the visual mode variant (`<leader>gi(` should work already). Unfortunately, your implementation misses the code for that; it only handles normal mode (and only characterwise motions at that) so far. In visual mode, the `type` argument contains a `v` / `V` / `<C-v>` value; you need to handle that, too:

```
function! GrepOperator(type)
    if a:type ==# 'char'
        normal! `[v`]y
    elseif a:type ==# 'v'
        normal! `<v`>y
    else
        return
    endif

    echom shellescape(@@)
endfunction
```

As the visual selection is defined by the `'<,'>` marks, you need to use those, not the previously mentioned `'[,']`.

`:help :map-operator` has another example (and uses a slightly different approach), and also shows how to handle the different values of `'selection'` correctly.

Comment: I am trying to interpret the command: `\`[v\`]y` as: Go to the first character of the word under the cursor or motion command. Then go to visual mode. Then select till last character of the word or motion command value(character). Then yank it. It correct explanation or I am not getting the understanding correctly.

Comment: Yes, this captures the text that is covered by the motion that is used on the operator function in the default register.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: Ah, glad I could help! Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.